# How To Find Out Where the Short URLs Point To with Javascript

Tags: javascript, short-url

I have created a short url, let say `https://my.short.link/foo`, that is pointing to `https://my.other.website/bar`.

How can I retrieve this url with a javascript method inside the browser? (I'm using angular)

Comment: You could try fetching it, but I don't know if that would give you the resolved URL or not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Astonishingly, yes, if the service does a simple redirect, the target URL is accessible as `response.url` (without the hash fragment, oddly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on how `my.short.link` handles processing the URL when you request it.

- Type 1: A really basic service might use a [redirection response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages) (HTTP 302, etc).
- Type 2: Or it might use a successful response serving an HTML page with a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...>` tag in it.
- Type 3: Or it might use a successful response serving an HTML page doing the redirection via JavaScript.

#### Browser

If you mean you want to do this in a browser, you **might** be able to get the information for service Type 1 above, but not for other services.

As [evolutionxbox says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053979/how-to-find-out-where-the-short-urls-point-to-with-javascript/72054044#comment127315637_72053979), you could try [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), and surprisingly (to me!) **if** the service handles requests with a simple redirection response, you do see a new URL in the response, but it wont have the hash fragment:

```js
fetch("https://tsplay.dev/wEv6gN")
.then(r => {
    if (!r.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${r.status}`);
    }
    for (const [key, value] of r.headers) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
    console.log(r.url);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

That URL, `https://tsplay.dev/wEv6gN`, redirects to `https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGB5ARgKwKbBQB0AZgE554BeeAFAN4CwAUDGzBCALZ4BcMARgBMAZgA0LdjAA24AOb96AIgRLeSrEoC+E1u2kBLaPwDaS4EoC6uqSBL8lSm+wRksBqGVcBPfmACu0tLObFAAFgZgchD8AkRCuloAlADcLCxQ3gAOePBICAD6ANZ43mgwJd52MJk51YjIacwsJP5ghAbg8CAA6iBkRbRF-A2FlUkwTHps0niwAG4I0v656KMmRZZNUgD0O0QHLFpAA` via a 302 ("Moved Permanently") redirect response. In the code above, we only see `https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?`. But maybe that's enough for your purposes.

But that won't work for types 2 and 3 above. You'd have to be able to read and parse the HTML, and the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent code running on your origin from accessing that HTML. You could try opening it in an `iframe` (though I suspect you don't really want to *visit* the page, you just want to get its URL), but the same issue applies: Even when the `iframe` goes to the target location, you won't be able to access that because of the SOP.

#### Node.js Or Similar

If you mean in Node.js or some other non-browser environment, then:

- For a Type 1 service, you could do an HTTP request and look at the redirection information.
- For a Type 2 service, you could do the HTTP request, parse the HTML, and look for the tag.
- For a Type 3, you'd need to use a headless browser (Puppeteer, etc.) to capture where it was going.

Comment: Thx for this amazing answer, initially, it was the `Type 1` inside a browser. but I do get a `301  strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. I still see in the Response Headers the location, which it what I would like to have, but I've read that I shall not access to it. Do you have any Idea ? I do think I'll have to go through the `Node.js Or Similar` step

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet - No, no further ideas I'm afraid. I suspect you will need to go through a server. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm also afraid so I'll go with Node.js and update you're answer accordingly. Thx again & Happy coding to !